# Incorrect output for sample solution

Tags: java

I'm doing leetcode's 540. Single Element in a Sorted Array problem.
I found an answer online. 
This answer can be successfully submitted on the leetcode website. But when I run this program on the compiler, it outputs an answer of `8`. The answer I should get is `2` not `8`.
I don't quite understand why the last part of this program is `if (left == 0) return nums[0]`.

Can someone tell me why?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] n = {1,2,3,3,4,4,8,8};
        int ans = singleNonDuplicate(n);
        System.out.println(ans);
}

private static int singleNonDuplicate(int[] nums) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = nums.length - 1;

    while (left + 1 < right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        int num = nums[mid];
        if (num != nums[mid - 1] && num != nums[mid + 1]) return num;

        if (mid % 2 == 0) {
            if (num == nums[mid - 1]) {
                right = mid;
            } else {
                left = mid;
            }
        } else {
            if (num == nums[mid - 1]) {
                left = mid;
            } else {
                right = mid;
            }
        }
    }

    if (left == 0) return nums[0];
    return nums[nums.length - 1];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would not go around online searching for solutions to problems without actually understanding what the solution does.

However, the problem you are having is caused by the fact that there are two numbers in your input array that do not repeat. Those two numbers that never repeat are '1' and '2'. If you look at your program you will notice that the last return statement returns the last element of the array which in your case is the number '8'. That is why you are getting the return value you do not desire.

Using this array will allow your 'singleNonDuplicate(int[])' method to return the number '2'.

```java
int[] n = {1,1,2,3,3,4,4,8,8};
```